# Indexing from first row of attribute table with Python

Tags: qgis, python, attribute-table, qgis-variable

I'm just trying to extract the variable value of the 7th column of the first row in a vector layer. I'm not sure how to index the table exactly though. I included the lines I wrote, which I imagine are pretty close. I think the third line is what needs tweaking?

```
 lyr = iface.activeLayer()
 features = lyr.getFeatures()

 attrs = features.attributes()
 var = attrs[7]
```

I found solutions where they go through a loop of all the features but I'm trying to avoid this if possible.

Comment: The seventh item in a zero-based list has a radix of six.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getFeatures()` returns an iterator object. You can use instead:

```
feature = lyr.getFeature(0)
```

then you can fetch a list using feature.attributes(), or

`lyr.getFeature(0).attribute(6)` for directly extracting 7th column of first row.

Answer (score 1):

A recipe to get first row and then 7th column

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

# Get First feature
feat1 = next(lyr.getFeatures())

var = feat1[6] # column index start at 0
# or
var = feat1[layer.fields().indexFromName('column7name')]
```